# iOS10 WkWebView Data URL decoding failed

Tags: ios, png, wkwebview, ios10, data-url

Did anyone experience problems in `iOS10` displaying PNG's as data-url?

This code works flawless in `WkWebView` `iOS9`, but it fails with 'Failed to load resource: Data URL decoding failed' in **WkWebView** iOS10:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA ...[skipped]... ">
```

Displaying JPEG's works fine in both `iOS9` and `iOS10`.

Comment: We have the same issue on iOS 10, but only when the image is fetched from the file system (Cache folder). Is it the same for you ? BTW, we use JPG.

Comment: Yes, my images are fetched from the filesystem as well.

Comment: Apparently, there is a stacking issue when saving a file in the FS with the Cordova Plugin File. Can you check your base64, and see if the image is maybe stored twice ?

Comment: I am having the same issue but it is intermittent. I am also using Cordova, @RemySan can you post a link to that Cordova File Plugin issue? Did anyone find a workaround? I need transparency so can't use JPG

Comment: The png stored seems fine. When I download the container and open the png in Quicklook, everything looks ok. So it doesn't seem to me like the File plugin causes this.

Comment: I agree the png stored is good. But I use the cordova File plugin (FileReader.readAsDataURL) to read the file in and assign result to img.src; that is where javascript console gives me "Failed to load resource: Data URL decoding failed". The data url string in the console is not valid, I tried copying it into a test html. So I think it's either a problem with cordova FileReader.readAsDataURL or something in iOS 10 that talks to that file reader. Weird thing is it doesn't always happen, some pngs work fine for me hmmm.

Comment: Same problem with iOS 11.

Comment: having same issue on iOS11.2

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For anyone experiencing this problem, it disappeared after upgrading to Cordova iOS 4.3.0.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have found a bug for iOS10 Apple has to fix. I also ran into these kind of problems embedding PNG images as data-url in a PDF. I use pdfmake javascript library (pdfmake.org) to generate PDF's client side and when I embed a PNG image it gives me errors. JPG images work just fine.

Unfortunately I only see one workaround now and that is to use JPG images in stead of PNGs.